# How can this be translated into postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, outer-join

I am fairly new to sql in general, and I am trying to work with a database which is extremely large. Now, on the website's examples, there is this query

```
SELECT m.chembl_id AS compound_chembl_id,   
s.canonical_smiles,   
r.compound_key,   
NVL(TO_CHAR(d.pubmed_id),d.doi) AS pubmed_id_or_doi,   
a.description                   AS assay_description,   act.standard_type,   
act.standard_relation,   
act.standard_value,   
act.standard_units,   
act.activity_comment 
FROM compound_structures s,   
molecule_dictionary m,   
compound_records r,   
docs d,   
activities act,   
assays a,   
target_dictionary t 
WHERE s.molregno (+) = m.molregno 
AND m.molregno       = r.molregno 
AND r.record_id      = act.record_id 
AND r.doc_id         = d.doc_id 
AND act.assay_id     = a.assay_id 
AND a.tid            = t.tid 
AND t.chembl_id      = 'CHEMBL1827';
```

because of this (+) and this NVL I assumed it is Oracle. I am working on pgadmin4 and all my attempts at translating this after doing some research, resulted in errors. Example of my attempt and the error given bellow

```
SELECT m.chembl_id AS compound_chembl_id,   
s.canonical_smiles,   
r.compound_key,   
COALESCE(CAST(d.pubmed_id AS varchar),d.doi)    AS pubmed_id_or_doi,   
a.description                                   AS assay_description,   
act.standard_type,   
act.standard_relation,   
act.standard_value,   
act.standard_units,   
act.activity_comment 
FROM compound_structures s,   
compound_records r,   
docs d,   
activities act,   
assays a,   
target_dictionary t
LEFT OUTER JOIN molecule_dictionary m ON s.molregno = m.molregno
WHERE m.molregno      = r.molregno 
AND r.record_id      = act.record_id 
AND r.doc_id         = d.doc_id 
AND act.assay_id     = a.assay_id 
AND a.tid            = t.tid 
AND t.chembl_id      = 'CHEMBL1827';

ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "s"
LINE 16: LEFT OUTER JOIN molecule_dictionary m ON s.molregno = m.molr...
                                              ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "s", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the 
query.
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 492
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't mix the old, ancient implicit joins and explicit JOIN operator:

```
SELECT m.chembl_id AS compound_chembl_id,   
       s.canonical_smiles,   
       r.compound_key,   
       COALESCE(CAST(d.pubmed_id AS varchar),d.doi)  AS pubmed_id_or_doi,   
       a.description                   AS assay_description,   
       act.standard_type,   
       act.standard_relation,   
       act.standard_value,   
       act.standard_units,   
       act.activity_comment 
FROM compound_structures s
  LEFT JOIN molecule_dictionary m ON s.molregno = m.molregno 
  JOIN compound_records r         ON m.molregno = r.molregno 
  JOIN docs d                     ON r.doc_id = d.doc_id 
  JOIN activities act             ON r.record_id = act.record_id 
  JOIN assays a                   ON act.assay_id = a.assay_id 
  JOIN target_dictionary t        ON a.tid = t.tid 
WHERE t.chembl_id      = 'CHEMBL1827';
```

I hope I got the direction of the outer join correct - I haven't used that Oracle syntax for decades (note that even Oracle recommends to stop using it).

But the inner join on the following tables effectively turns that outer join back into an inner join - I don't think the Oracle syntax changes that (meaning: I think that attempt on an outer join in the original query was wrong to begin with). So maybe you can simplify the `LEFT JOIN` to a `JOIN`. I am not sure if that outer join actually makes sense in the Oracle query.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I think I understand the query more now!

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
SELECT 
    m.chembl_id AS compound_chembl_id,   
    s.canonical_smiles,   
    r.compound_key,   
    COALESCE((d.pubmed_id)::text, d.doi) AS pubmed_id_or_doi,   
    a.description AS assay_description,   
    act.standard_type,   
    act.standard_relation,   
    act.standard_value,   
    act.standard_units,   
    act.activity_comment 
FROM 
    compound_structures s 
    INNER JOIN molecule_dictionary m ON s.molregno = m.molregno   
    INNER JOIN compound_records r ON m.molregno = r.molregno 
    INNER JOIN docs d ON r.doc_id = d.doc_id 
    INNER JOIN activities act ON r.record_id = act.record_id 
    INNER JOIN assays a ON act.assay_id = a.assay_id 
    INNER JOIN target_dictionary t ON a.tid = t.tid AND t.chembl_id = 'CHEMBL1827'
```

Rationale:

- use standard, explicit joins everywhere; old school joins have been deprecated 20 years ago!
- `COALESCE()` is more standard than `NVL()`
- a `LEFT JOIN` followed by `INNER JOIN`s that relate to columns coming for the left table is actually equivalent to `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I do agree on that, and my query is not using that syntax. Right now I don't understand the downvote, but I am probably missing something!

Comment: Before you commented on the outer join, it looked as if you didn't understand that the original query was using an outer join - but your observation bout the following inner joins making the outer join useless is spot on (I didn't downvote)

Comment: Yes I posted the query first, then added the explanation, that's all...

Comment: I didn't down-vote either! Thank you for the help and for explaining!